# Determining the extended interfaces of a Class

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I need to determine if a Class object representing an interface extends another interface, ie:

```
 package a.b.c.d;
    public Interface IMyInterface extends a.b.d.c.ISomeOtherInterface{
    }
```

according to [the spec](http://web.archive.org/web/20100705124350/http://java.sun.com:80/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) Class.getSuperClass() will return null for an Interface.

> If this Class represents either the
>   Object class, an interface, a
>   primitive type, or void, then null is
>   returned.

Therefore the following won't work.

```
Class interface = Class.ForName("a.b.c.d.IMyInterface")
Class extendedInterface = interface.getSuperClass();
if(extendedInterface.getName().equals("a.b.d.c.ISomeOtherInterface")){
    //do whatever here
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use Class.getInterfaces such as:

```
Class<?> c; // Your class
for(Class<?> i : c.getInterfaces()) {
     // test if i is your interface
}
```

Also the following code might be of help, it will give you a set with all super-classes and interfaces of a certain class:

```
public static Set<Class<?>> getInheritance(Class<?> in)
{
    LinkedHashSet<Class<?>> result = new LinkedHashSet<Class<?>>();

    result.add(in);
    getInheritance(in, result);

    return result;
}

/**
 * Get inheritance of type.
 * 
 * @param in
 * @param result
 */
private static void getInheritance(Class<?> in, Set<Class<?>> result)
{
    Class<?> superclass = getSuperclass(in);

    if(superclass != null)
    {
        result.add(superclass);
        getInheritance(superclass, result);
    }

    getInterfaceInheritance(in, result);
}

/**
 * Get interfaces that the type inherits from.
 * 
 * @param in
 * @param result
 */
private static void getInterfaceInheritance(Class<?> in, Set<Class<?>> result)
{
    for(Class<?> c : in.getInterfaces())
    {
        result.add(c);

        getInterfaceInheritance(c, result);
    }
}

/**
 * Get superclass of class.
 * 
 * @param in
 * @return
 */
private static Class<?> getSuperclass(Class<?> in)
{
    if(in == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if(in.isArray() && in != Object[].class)
    {
        Class<?> type = in.getComponentType();

        while(type.isArray())
        {
            type = type.getComponentType();
        }

        return type;
    }

    return in.getSuperclass();
}
```

Edit: Added some code to get all super-classes and interfaces of a certain class.

Comment: Looks to me like making it more complicated then it is; reimplementing what Java already provides. Assuming all code here is correct, it'll just give the same answer as the one-liner isAssignableFrom from other answers.

Answer (score 10):

```
if (interface.isAssignableFrom(extendedInterface))
```

is what you want

i always get the ordering backwards at first but recently realized that it's the exact opposite of using instanceof

```
if (extendedInterfaceA instanceof interfaceB)
```

is the same thing but you have to have instances of the classes rather than the classes themselves

Answer (score 2):

Does Class.isAssignableFrom() do what you need?

```
Class baseInterface = Class.forName("a.b.c.d.IMyInterface");
Class extendedInterface = Class.forName("a.b.d.c.ISomeOtherInterface");

if ( baseInterface.isAssignableFrom(extendedInterface) )
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Class.getInterfaces();

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (Class c : list.getClass().getInterfaces()) {
    System.out.println(c.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Liast<Class> getAllInterfaces(Class<?> clazz){
    List<Class> interfaces = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(interfaces,clazz.getInterfaces());
    if(!clazz.getSuperclass().equals(Object.class)){
        interfaces.addAll(getAllInterfaces(clazz.getSuperclass()));
    }
    return interfaces ;
}
```

Comment: You should add some context explaining your answer rather than just providing code.