# If a class is implementing two interfaces ,which one is actual the parent interface for that class in java

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance

If a class is implementing  two interfaces, which inteface is actual the parent interface for that class in Java

```
interface A  { 
    void m1(); 
}

interface B {
    void  m1(); 
}


public class C implements A,B {

    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("m1 method !!!");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
         C obj = new  C();
         obj.m1();                     
         ((A)obj).m1();            
         ((B)obj).m1();           

         A objAsA = (A)obj;
         objAsA.m1();               

         B objAsB = (B) obj ;
         objAsB.m1();              
     }

}
```

Comment: that was the whole purpose of having interface, to solve the situation when we need to inherit from more than one source, so there is no parent in interfaces,

Answer (score 3):

There is no such concept as "the actual parent interface" in Java. All interfaces are on equal footing as the supertypes of the class. That doesn't change even in your case where both interfaces declare the same method signature: the same method in `C` implements both `A` and `B`.

BTW you don't need a cast operator to accomplish an upcast:

```
A objAsA = obj;
objAsA.m1();               

B objAsB = obj;
objAsB.m1();
```

Comment: All interfaces are on equal footing as the supertypes of the class,can u please elaborate this what yu have said ?

Comment: C has two supertypes: A and B. Neither is "the" supertype.

Answer (score 1):

`parent` is a concept related for `extension` not `implementation`.

Comment: can you prove it ??with an example that parent isa concept related for extension not for implementation

Comment: As you only can `extend`one class, that class is the `parent`

Answer (score 1):

From Java [Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5)

```
interface Fish  { int getNumberOfScales(); }
interface Piano { int getNumberOfScales(); }
class Tuna implements Fish, Piano {
    // You can tune a piano, but can you tuna fish?
    public int getNumberOfScales() { return 91; }
}
```

> the method getNumberOfScales in class Tuna has a name, signature, and return type that matches the method declared in interface Fish and also matches the method declared in interface Piano; it is considered to implement both.

So its considered you implement **BOTH**

Comment: can we say both of the interfaces are parent interfaces for  tuna ?ferdinand-neman

Comment: You implement both contract specified by each interface. You can cast it to either interface.

Comment: i agree but is there any concept of "parent interface " in this program ??Ferdinanad neman

Comment: If you think about `inheritance`, the Tuna is inheriting the behavioral contract from both `Fish` and `Piano`. `Tuna` is the **implementation** of _blueprints_ specified by both interface. If you think about `polymorphism`, the implemented `Tuna` can be treated as a `Fish` and also can be treated as `Piano`. There is no such thing as parent and child in this context. Its a mere relation of **specification** and **implementation** of behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense. You do not have 'parent' interfaces in java.
An interface is like a contract, you 'promise' to provide the methods listed in the interface. You are getting inheritance mixed up with interfaces.

Inheritance is where one class inherits parts of another class. 
Like Dog -> Husky, Dog -> Poodle

An interface is where every Animal promises to have a method called public String getSpecies() for example.

In case you want to find all the interfaces a class has look at this question.
[Determining the extended interfaces of a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116587/determining-the-extended-interfaces-of-a-class)

---

While an interface can extend other interfaces, a 'normal' class doesn't have the concept of parent interfaces.
Thank you to akhil for spotting this.

You can think of child classes as specialisations of their parents, each level being more specific. 
Animal -> Dog -> Husky. However every lower level has some common functionality with its siblings. All Dogs can bark(), all Animals can move().

Now try applying this logic to interfaces and you will see that it doesn't really make sense. An interface exists only to ensure that every class has a specific ability. All animals need to breathe, regardless of what species so you can make Animals implement Breathable. Which ensures that every animal has a method breathe().

Comment: We do have concept of parent interfaces in Java. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html

Comment: in the above program A,B both are parent interfaces of C??akhil_mittal

Comment: @akhil_mittal you are correct, although that applies to an interface extending other interfaces not a 'plainl class. I will update my answer thank you. Ramesh, you can think of it like that but its not exactly true. A class doesn't have parent interfaces.

Comment: i didn't get  exactly what you are saying ,can u please elaborate it with detailed explaination..thanks in advance RainyCats

Comment: @RameshRaj what exactly don't you get? Explain to me the differences between  inheritance and interfaces. Then tell me what you don't understand.

Comment: inheritance is smethng which a child class  inherits the properties of parent class ,so ,multiple inheritance is not supported inorder to support  multiple inheritance interface came into existence so that u can declare methods in interface  and implement them in subclasses now what ever u xplained in the last paragraph about  breathable i didn't get exactly...can u please try to explain with a program....

Comment: "..inorder to support multiple inheritance interface came into existence..."  do not think of it like that. In inheritance you do not need to implement the methods again, you inherit them, but with interfaces you declare the methods they need to have and each class implements it themselves.

Comment: ok,so can u please  explain me aboutu r example of Animal -> Dog -> Husky one more time.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here class `C` implements both the interfaces and `C is A` and `C is B` as well.

Answer (score 0):

An implemenation means you need to use that method in your class. So there is no parent of it. With extendions this can be, but then there can't be 2 parents to 1 class. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    C c = new C();
    c.m1();
}

class A {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("A printing");
    }
}

class B {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("B printing");
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("C print");
    }
}
```

printing: "C print"

C can't extend B at the same time. But it does override the method of class A. If C did not contain the method "m1()" then the method from class A was used and the console would print: "A printing"